# SQL Syntax error in Update from script?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm trying to do a fairly simple update of one column from one table to the same column in another.

I have two tables:

container (id, barcode_1, location)

test(id, barcode_1, location)

Both tables are exactly the same except for the barcode_1 column. I want to update container.barcode_1 with the values from test.barcode_1 on all matching ids.

This is the code I'm using:

```
update container
set container.barcode_1 = test.barcode_1
FROM container INNER JOIN test ON container.id = test.id;
```

When I run that code, I get this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM container INNER JOIN test ON container.id = test.id' at line 3

Any ideas one why this might be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` syntax is wrong here. It should be

```
update container
INNER JOIN test ON container.id = test.id
set container.barcode_1 = test.barcode_1;
```

(OR) Using table alias

```
update container c 
INNER JOIN test t ON c.id = t.id
set c.barcode_1 = t.barcode_1;
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I was busting my brain trying to figure out what I was doing incorrectly.

Comment: This must be limited to MySql? This is valid Sql Server syntax

Comment: @Brad, question is for `MySQL` ... got it from the error statement. For `MSSQL` it would be bit different but the provided syntax in answer is ANSI compliant.

Comment: Aye aye, I changed the tags.